# ¿Cómo convertir número a palabras en SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentando convertir un número a palabras.

```
Por ejemplo: 150 = Ciento cincuenta.
```

Sé que hay muchos códigos que pueden hacerlo fácilmente, el detalle está en que actualmente estoy utilizando la plataforma `Oracle Cloud BI Publisher`, y no puedo -por cuestión de permisos del mismo `Oracle`- hacer un `create, update, drop, delete o insert`.

Quisiera saber si podrían ayudarme con algún código que no use `CREATE FUNCTION` o similares, sino que sea todo con `SELECT, FROM, WHEN CASE`, etc.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Podrías echar un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour , ¿Qué llevas escrito? Si solo es un SELECT puedes usar un SELECT WHEN CASE

Comment: Hola, tengo una tabla de Empleados, con atributos: ID_EMPLOYEER, SUELDO y necesito mostrar sus SUELDOS tanto número como en letras, por ejemplo: E01, 250, doscientos cincuenta   E02, 300, trescientos   E03, 100, cien y así

Comment: Las veces que me ha tocado eso, las palabras las genera el codigo con alguna biblioteca de codigo para eso y se guarda el texto completo en la base, es decir la base no genera eso al menos nunca lo he visto, y si es para presentacion las tecnologias de reportes tambien ya tienen sus propias funciones que generan esas palabras como Crystal Reports o Telerik

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste crear un [bloque de codigo](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/sql/construyendo-con-bloques-parte-1-1549135-esa.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He realizado la implementación para convertir a letras la parte de un número menor a mil, dado que, si entiendes la mecánica, realizar los pasos para procesar cualquier otra cantidad de bloques de tres dígitos es un trabajo de copiar, pegar y hacer pequeños ajustes, además de concatenar las palabras `'mil'`, `'millones'`, etc.

Lo que hago en el ejemplo es, primero, construir una *CTE* con números de ejemplo, llamado `Numero`, luego en el *CTE* `PreProcesado1` los separo en dígitos: `unidades`, `decenas`, `centenas`. Para el ejemplo necesitaba solamente los últimos 3, pero he dejado los siguientes tres a manera de ejemplo. De la misma manera puedes obtener las unidades, decenas y centenas de millón, y así hasta la cantidad de dígitos que quieras soportar.

Finalmente, con `Unidades`, `Decenas` y `Centenas`, procedo a *calcular* el valor en letras.

```
with
Numero as (
select 152 N from dual
union all select 14587 from dual
union all select 14 from dual
union all select 7816 from dual
union all select 174 from dual
union all select 458 from dual
union all select 17548987 from dual
union all select 458157 from dual
union all select 14850 from dual
union all select 21410 from dual
union all select 100 from dual
union all select 457500 from dual
union all select 82100 from dual
)
,
PreProcesado1 as (
select   N
       , floor(mod(N, 1000000) / 100000) MillarCentenas
       , floor(mod(N, 100000) / 10000) MillarDecenas
       , floor(mod(N, 10000) / 1000) MillarUnidades
       , floor(mod(N, 1000) / 100) Centenas
       , floor(mod(N, 100) / 10) Decenas
       , floor(mod(N, 10)) Unidades
  from Numero
)
select   N
       ,  case Centenas
            when 0 then ''
            when 1 then case when Decenas = 0 and Unidades = 0 then 'cien ' else 'ciento ' end
            when 2 then 'doscientos '
            when 3 then 'trescientos '
            when 4 then 'cuatrocientos '
            when 5 then 'quinientos '
            when 6 then 'seiscientos '
            when 7 then 'setecientos '
            when 8 then 'ochocientos '
            when 9 then 'novecientos '
          end
       || case Decenas
            when 0 then ''
            when 2 then 'veinte '
            when 3 then 'treinta '
            when 4 then 'cuarenta '
            when 5 then 'cincuenta '
            when 6 then 'sesenta '
            when 7 then 'setenta '
            when 8 then 'ochenta '
            when 9 then 'noventa '
            when 1 then
              case Unidades
                when 0 then 'diez '
                when 1 then 'once '
                when 2 then 'doce '
                when 3 then 'trece '
                when 4 then 'catorce '
                when 5 then 'quince '
                else 'dieci'
              end
          end
       || case when Decenas > 1 and Unidades <> 0 then 'y ' else '' end
       || case 
            when Decenas = 1 and Unidades < 6 then '' 
            else
              case Unidades 
                when 0 then ''
                when 1 then 'uno'
                when 2 then 'dos'
                when 3 then 'tres'
                when 4 then 'cuatro'
                when 5 then 'cinco'
                when 6 then 'seis'
                when 7 then 'siete'
                when 8 then 'ocho'
                when 9 then 'nueve'
              end
            end 
       NumeroEnLetras
  from PreProcesado1
```

El resultado obtenido de la ejecución del script es el siguiente:

```
         N, NUMEROENLETRAS
       152, ciento cincuenta y dos
     14587, quinientos ochenta y siete
        14, catorce 
      7816, ochocientos dieciseis
       174, ciento setenta y cuatro
       458, cuatrocientos cincuenta y ocho
  17548987, novecientos ochenta y siete
    458157, ciento cincuenta y siete
     14850, ochocientos cincuenta 
     21410, cuatrocientos diez 
       100, cien 
    457500, quinientos 
     82100, cien
```

Como he dicho antes, solamente se *convierte* los últimos tres dígitos y queda como ejercicio para el lector *completar* la conversión hasta la cantidad de dígitos que desee soportar.

Puedes ejecutar el [script de números a letras](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ht8qoyjmv97kwrz0zg2ku0wnw) en vivo visitando [este enlace](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ht8qoyjmv97kwrz0zg2ku0wnw).

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Este código si es aceptado por la plataforma que uso, muchas gracias amigo. Ahora solo me toca editarlo para número más grandes ¡Éxitos!

Comment: Un gusto, me alegra ser de ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Excelente respuesta paisano.

Comment: @alanfcm la lucha se hace... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer para lograr lo que pides sería una consulta como esta más o menos:

```
SELECT UPPER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(8,'J'),'Jsp')) AS valor
FROM dual;
```

Pero el resultado es : `EIGHT`

La respuesta es en inglés, para poder obtener el resultado en español es necesario implementar PL/SQL, ya que actualmente no existe la posibilidad que devuelta un resultado en español sin lo anterior:

[Existe un código ya realizado](http://oracle-forms.blogspot.com/2009/01/convertir-numeros-letras-usando-plsql.html) que responde está pregunta, el cual realiza la conversión a Español y a Catalán, pero utilizando PL/SQL

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Sí he revisado ese segundo código y me funciona correctamente en el Oracle SQL Developer. Sin embargo, la plataforma que actualmente estoy utilizando (Oracle Cloud BI Publisher) no me permite modificar su base de datos nativa (por eso no puedo utilizar un create, insert, drop, delete o alter). El primer código me funciona bien en ambas plataformas pero -como dijiste- solo arroja el resultado en inglés. De todas maneras muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Cree la siguiente función en SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_NumberToWords](@Number as BIGINT)

    RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)

AS

BEGIN
    -- Crear tablas temporales para guardar numeros y palabras especificas
      DECLARE @Below20 TABLE (ID int identity(0,1), Word varchar(32))
      DECLARE @Below100 TABLE (ID int identity(2,1), Word varchar(32))
      DECLARE @Below1000 TABLE (ID int identity(1,1), Word varchar(32))
    -- Insertar los numero del 0 al 19 en la primera tabla
      INSERT @Below20 (Word) VALUES
                        ( 'Cero'), ('Uno'),( 'Dos' ), ( 'Tres'),
                        ( 'Cuatro' ), ( 'Cinco' ), ( 'Seis' ), ( 'Siete' ),
                        ( 'Ocho'), ( 'Nueve'), ( 'Dies'), ( 'Once' ),
                        ( 'Doce' ), ( 'Trece' ), ( 'Catorce'),
                        ( 'Quince' ), ('Dieciseis' ), ( 'Diecisiete'),
                        ('Dieciocho' ), ( 'Diecinueve' )
    -- Insertar los multiplos de 10 hasta el 90 en la segunda tabla
       INSERT @Below100 VALUES ('Veinte'), ('Treinta'),('Cuarenta'), ('Cincuenta'),
                               ('Sesenta'), ('Setenta'), ('Ochenta'), ('Noventa')
    -- Inserte los multiplos de 100 hasta el 900 en la tercera tabla
       INSERT @Below1000 VALUES ('Ciento'), ('Docientos'), ('Trecientos'), ('Cuatrocientos'),
                               ('Quinientos'), ('Seiscientos'), ('Setecientos'), ('Ochocientos') , ('Novecientos')

DECLARE @Words varchar(1024) =
(

  SELECT CASE
    WHEN @Number = 0 THEN  ''

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1 AND 19
      THEN (SELECT Word FROM @Below20 WHERE ID=@Number)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 20 AND 99  
     THEN CASE WHEN @Number BETWEEN 21 AND 29
               THEN 'Veinti' + dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 10) 
               ELSE (SELECT Word FROM @Below100 WHERE ID=@Number/10)+ ' y ' +
               dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 10)
           END

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 100 AND 999  
     THEN  CASE WHEN @Number = 100 
                THEN 'Cien' 
                ELSE (SELECT Word FROM @Below1000 WHERE ID=@Number/100)+' '+
                dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 100)
           END

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000 AND 999999  
     THEN  CASE WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000 AND 1199 
                THEN 'Mil ' + dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000) 
                ELSE (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000))+' Mil '+
                dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000) 
           END

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000 AND 999999999  
     THEN CASE WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000 AND 1999999 
               THEN 'Un Million '+
                    dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000)
               ELSE (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000))+' Milliones '+
                    dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000)
          END

   WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 999999999999  
    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000))+' Billion '+
         dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000)
   ELSE 'NUMERO INVALIDO' 
   END
)

SELECT @Words = RTRIM(@Words)
SELECT @Words = RTRIM(LEFT(@Words,len(@Words)-1))
                 WHERE RIGHT(@Words,1)='-'
RETURN (@Words)
END
```

Así puede probar la función:

```
SELECT 'Numero en palabras' = dbo.Fn_NumberToWords('numero')
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Tengo este Package que recién modifique para que soportara números mucho mas grandes y quedó de la siguiente manera
Package

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Mto_Escrito IS
  FUNCTION monto_escrito (p_monto  IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;
  PROCEDURE cientos (p_cantidad IN VARCHAR2,
                     p_monto    IN NUMBER,
                     p_parte    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                     p_longitud IN OUT NUMBER,
                     p_cero     IN VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE decenas (p_cantidad IN VARCHAR2,
                     p_parte    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                     p_longitud IN OUT NUMBER);
  PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES(cientos, WNDS);
  PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES(decenas, WNDS);
  PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES(monto_escrito, WNDS);
END;
/
```

Package Body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Mto_Escrito IS
/***********************************************************************/
/* MONTO_ESCRITO: Retorna el valor en letras de una cantidad numerica. */
/***********************************************************************/
FUNCTION monto_escrito (p_monto  IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  num_letra VARCHAR2(18);
  longitud  NUMBER(10);
  contador  NUMBER(10);
  aux       VARCHAR2(2);
  parte     VARCHAR2(20);
  partee     VARCHAR2(30);
  tempo     VARCHAR2(18);
  may       NUMBER(14,2);
  mil_mil   VARCHAR2(50);
  p_letra   VARCHAR2(250);
BEGIN
  -- Coloca ceros a la izquierda hasta completar 16 digitos
  tempo := SUBSTR(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(p_monto,'00000000000000.00')),1,16);
  num_letra := tempo;
  contador  := 1;

  -- Evalua la primera terna (Millardos) del monto
  IF SUBSTR(num_letra,1,3) <> '000' THEN
    -- verifica si hay valor en la centena
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,1,1) <> '0' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,1,1);
      cientos (aux,p_monto,parte,longitud,SUBSTR(num_letra,2,2));
      contador := contador + longitud;
      p_letra  := parte;
    END IF;
    -- Evalua si hay valor en las decenas
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,2,2) <> '00' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,2,2);
      decenas (aux,parte,longitud);
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||parte;
      contador := contador + longitud;
    END IF;
    -- Evalua si el resto del numero tiene valor
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,4,3) = '000' THEN -- E.A.   POSICION 4 AL 9   '000000000'
      MIL_MIL  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||'MIL MILLONES ';
      contador := contador + 13;
    ELSE
      MIL_MIL  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||'MIL ';
      contador := contador + 4;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  -- Blanquea p_letra
  p_letra := NULL;
  
  IF SUBSTR(num_letra,4,5) = '00000' AND SUBSTR(p_monto,1,1)=',' THEN

cientos(0,SUBSTR(num_letra,14,2),parte,longitud,SUBSTR(num_letra,2,2));
decenas(SUBSTR(num_letra,14,2),partee,longitud);
contador := contador + longitud;
p_letra  := parte || partee;

END IF;

  -- Evalua la segunda terna (Millones) del monto
  IF SUBSTR(num_letra,4,3) <> '000' THEN
    -- verifica si hay valor en la centena
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,4,1) <> '0' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,4,1);
      cientos (aux,p_monto,parte,longitud,SUBSTR(num_letra,5,2));
      contador := contador + longitud;
      p_letra  := parte;
    END IF;
    -- evalua si hay valor en las decenas
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,5,2) <> '00' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,5,2);
      decenas (aux,parte,longitud);
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||parte;
      contador := contador + longitud;
    END IF;

    -- Verifica si la terna es mas de un millon (Contador es mayor que 4)
    IF contador = 4 THEN
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||'MILLON ';
      contador := contador + 7;
    ELSE
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||'MILLONES ';
      contador := contador + 9;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  -- Evalua la tercera terna (miles) del numero
  IF SUBSTR(num_letra,7,3) <> '000' THEN
    -- Evalua si las centenas tienen valor
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,7,1) <> '0' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,7,1);
      cientos(aux,p_monto,parte,longitud,SUBSTR(num_letra,8,2));
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||parte;
      contador := contador + longitud;
    END IF;
    -- Evalua si las decenas tienen valor
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,8,2) <> '00' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,8,2);
      decenas(aux,parte,longitud);
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||parte;
      contador := contador + longitud;
    END IF;
    -- Sufija el monto en letras  con la palabra MIL e incrementa el contador
    p_letra     := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||'MIL ';
    contador    := contador + 4;
  END IF;

  -- Evalua la cuarta terna (cientos) del numero
  IF SUBSTR(num_letra,10,3) <> '000' THEN
    -- Evalua si la centena tiene valor
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,10,1) <> '0' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,10,1);
      cientos(aux,p_monto,parte,longitud,SUBSTR(num_letra,11,2));
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||parte;
      contador := contador + longitud;
    END IF;
    -- Evalua si la decena tiene valor
    IF SUBSTR(num_letra,11,2) <> '00' THEN
      aux      := SUBSTR(num_letra,11,2);
      decenas(aux,parte,longitud);
      p_letra  := SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador)||parte;
      contador := contador + longitud;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  -- Si el monto involucra cantidades de millon, coloca ' DE '
  IF SUBSTR(num_letra,1,6) != '000000' AND  SUBSTR(num_letra,7,6) = '000000'  THEN
    p_letra := mil_mil || SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador+1) ||
               --' BOLIVARES CON ' ||
               ' CON ' ||
              SUBSTR(num_letra,14,2) ||'/100 CTMS';
  ELSIF SUBSTR(num_letra,4,5) = '00000' AND SUBSTR(p_monto,1,1)=',' THEN
     p_letra := mil_mil || p_letra ||' CTMS';
  ELSE
     p_letra := mil_mil || SUBSTR(p_letra,1,contador+1) ||
               --' BOLIVARES CON ' ||
               ' CON ' ||
              SUBSTR(num_letra,14,2) ||'/100 CTMS';
  END IF;

  -- Elimina doble espacio en blanco
  p_letra := REPLACE(p_letra,'  ',' ');
  p_letra := REPLACE (p_letra, 'UN CON','UNO CON');

  RETURN(RPAD(p_letra,LENGTH(p_letra)+5,'*'));
END;
/***********************************************************************/
/* CIENTOS: Retorna el valor en letras de las centenas de una cantidad */
/*          y la longitud que esta ocupa.                              */
/***********************************************************************/
PROCEDURE cientos (p_cantidad IN VARCHAR2,
                   p_monto    IN NUMBER,
                   p_parte    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                   p_longitud IN OUT NUMBER,
                   p_cero     IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  IF p_cantidad = '1'  THEN
    IF p_cero  = '00' THEN
      p_parte := 'CIEN ';
    ELSE
      p_parte := 'CIENTO ';
    END IF;
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '2' THEN
    p_parte    := 'DOSCIENTOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '3' THEN
    p_parte    := 'TRESCIENTOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '4' THEN
    p_parte    := 'CUATROCIENTOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '5' THEN
    p_parte    := 'QUINIENTOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '6' THEN
    p_parte    := 'SEISCIENTOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '7' THEN
    p_parte    := 'SETECIENTOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '8' THEN
    p_parte    := 'OCHOCIENTOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '9' THEN
    p_parte    := 'NOVECIENTOS ';
  END IF;
  IF p_cantidad = '0'  THEN
      p_parte    := 'CERO CON ';
  END IF;
  p_longitud := LENGTH(p_parte);
END;
/****************************************************************************/
/* DECENAS: Retorna el valor en letras de una cantidad expresada en decenas */
/*          y la longitud que esta ocupa.                                   */
/****************************************************************************/
PROCEDURE decenas (p_cantidad IN VARCHAR2,
                   p_parte    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                   p_longitud IN OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  IF p_cantidad = '01' THEN
    p_parte   := 'UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '02' THEN
    p_parte   := 'DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '03' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '04' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '05' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '06' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '07' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '08' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '09' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '10' THEN
    p_parte   := 'DIEZ ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '11' THEN
    p_parte   := 'ONCE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '12' THEN
    p_parte   := 'DOCE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '13' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TRECE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '14' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CATORCE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '15' THEN
    p_parte   := 'QUINCE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '16' THEN
    p_parte   := 'DIECISEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '17' THEN
    p_parte   := 'DIECISIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '18' THEN
    p_parte   := 'DIECIOCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '19' THEN
    p_parte   := 'DIECINUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '20' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '21' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTIUN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '22' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTIDOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '23' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTITRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '24' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTICUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '25' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTICINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '26' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTISEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '27' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTISIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '28' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTIOCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '29' THEN
    p_parte   := 'VEINTINUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '30' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '31' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '32' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '33' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '34' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '35' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '36' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '37' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '38' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '39' THEN
    p_parte   := 'TREINTA Y NUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '40' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '41' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '42' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '43' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '44' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '45' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '46' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '47' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '48' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '49' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CUARENTA Y NUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '50' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '51' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '52' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '53' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '54' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '55' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '56' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '57' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '58' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '59' THEN
    p_parte   := 'CINCUENTA Y NUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '60' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '61' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '62' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '63' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '64' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '65' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '66' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '67' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '68' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '69' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SESENTA Y NUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '70' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '71' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '72' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '73' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '74' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '75' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '76' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '77' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '78' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '79' THEN
    p_parte   := 'SETENTA Y NUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '80' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '81' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '82' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '83' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '84' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '85' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '86' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '87' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '88' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '89' THEN
    p_parte   := 'OCHENTA Y NUEVE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '90' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '91' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y UN ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '92' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y DOS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '93' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y TRES ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '94' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y CUATRO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '95' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y CINCO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '96' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y SEIS ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '97' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y SIETE ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '98' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y OCHO ';
  ELSIF p_cantidad = '99' THEN
    p_parte   := 'NOVENTA Y NUEVE ';
 END IF;
 p_longitud := LENGTH(p_parte);
END;
END;
/
```

Modo de ejecuón

```
select Mto_Escrito.monto_escrito(99999999999999.99) Resultado
FROM DUAL

Resultado
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
NOVECIENTOS NOVENTA Y NUEVE MIL NOVECIENTOS NOVENTA Y NUEVE MILLONES NOVECIENTOS NOVENTA Y NUEVE MIL NOVECIENTOS NOVENTA Y NUEVE CON 9./100 CTMS*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir un número a letras en SQL Server, se puede utilizar una función de usuario (UDF) que contenga el código necesario para realizar la conversión. Sin embargo, debido a la complejidad de la tarea, no existe una función de conversión de números a letras incorporada en TSQL.

Ahora aqui te dejo un link con el procedimiento [blog]: https://thedevelopmentstages.com/funcion-para-convertir-numero-a-letras-sql-server/

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]. Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aceptada de hace más de 4 años.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/374264)